# Deserializing a JSON object hierarchy into a hierarchy of Dictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#, json, windows-8

I'm in **.NET for WinRT (C#)** and I'd like to deserialize a JSON string to a `Dictionary<string, object>`, where the dictionary value can later be converted to the actual type.
The JSON string can contain an object hierarchy and I'd like to have child objects in `Dictionary<string, object>` as well.

Here's a sample JSON it should be able to handle:

```
{
  "Name":"John Smith",
  "Age":42,
  "Parent":
  {
    "Name":"Brian Smith",
    "Age":65,
    "Parent":
    {
       "Name":"James Smith",
       "Age":87,
    }
  }
}
```

I tried with the **DataContractJsonSerializer** doing as so:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
{
    DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true;

    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>), settings);
    Dictionary<string, object> results = (Dictionary<string, object>)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
}
```

This actually works fine for the first level, but then *"Parent"* is just an object which cannot be casted to a `Dictionary<string, object>`:

```
Dictionary<string, object> parent = (Dictionary<string, object>)results["Parent"];
Cannot cast 'results["Parent"]' (which has an actual type of 'object') to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>'
```

I then tried using **Json.NET** but child objects are JObject themselves being `IDictionary<string, JToken>`, which forces me to iterate through the full hierarchy and convert them over again.

Would someone know how to solve this problem using an existing serializer?

**EDIT**

I'm using `Dictionary<string, object>` because my objects vary from one server call to another (e.g. the *"Id"* property might be *"id"*, *"cust_id"* or *"customerId"* depending on the request) and as my app isn't the only app using those services, I can't change that, at least for now.

Therefore, I found it inconvenient to use *DataContractAttribute* and *DataMemberAttribute* in this situation.
Instead I'd like to store everything in a generic dictionary, and have a single strongly-typed property "Id" which looks for "id", "cust_id" or "customerId" in the dictionary making it transparent for the UI.

This system works great with JSON.NET, however if ever the server returns an object hierarchy, sub-objects will be stored as JObjects in my dictionary instead of another dictionary.

To sum-up, I'm looking for an efficient system to transform an object hierarchy into a hierarchy of `Dictionary<string, object>` using a JSON serializer available in WinRT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm addressing this same issue in a WinRT app using a combination of the JSON.NET library and the ExpandoObject class.  The library is able to deserialize JSON data quite nicely into ExpandoObjects, which implement IDictionary.  The value of an ExpandoObject's key-value pair may easily be treated as another ExpandoObject.

Here's the approach I used, adapted to your sample:

```
void LoadJSONData()
{
    string testData = "{ \"Name\":\"John Smith\", \"Age\":42, \"Parent\": { \"Name\":\"Brian Smith\", \"Age\":65, \"Parent\": { \"Name\":\"James Smith\", \"Age\":87, } } }";

    ExpandoObject dataObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(testData, new ExpandoObjectConverter());

    // Grab the parent object directly (if it exists) and treat as ExpandoObject
    var parentElement = dataObj.Where(el => el.Key == "Parent").FirstOrDefault();
    if (parentElement.Value != null && parentElement.Value is ExpandoObject)
    {
        ExpandoObject parentObj = (ExpandoObject)parentElement.Value;
        // do something with the parent object...
    }

    // Alternately, iterate through the properties of the expando
    foreach (var property in (IDictionary<String, Object>)dataObj)
    {
        if (property.Key == "Parent" && property.Value != null && property.Value is ExpandoObject)
        {
            foreach (var parentProp in (ExpandoObject)property.Value)
            {
                // do something with the properties in the parent expando
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, it looks like what I'm looking for. I'll give it a try today and see if it fits (functionally and perf-wise)!

Answer (score 3):

Try this piece of code snippet:

```
var d = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var results = d.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonString);
var parent = (Dictionary<string, object>)results["Parent"];
```

According to the reference, [JavaScriptSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) supports *Windows 8*.

For deserialization, [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) is also an option to be considered with *Windows 8* support.

**ADDED**, For `WinRT`:

1. Define the `DataContract` according to your JSON.

   ```
   [DataContract]
   public class CustomObject
   {
       [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
       public string Name { get; set; }

       [DataMember(Name = "Age")]
       public string Age { get; set; }

       [DataMember(Name = "Parent")]
       public Dictionary<string, object> Parent { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Use the `DataContract` class while deserialization.

   ```
   using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
   {
       DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings = 
               new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings();
       settings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true;

       DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = 
               new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(CustomObject), settings);

       CustomObject results = (CustomObject)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
       Dictionary<string, object> parent = results.Parent;
   }
   ```

Reference: [Creating .NET objects from JSON using DataContractJsonSerializer](http://kashfarooq.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/creating-net-objects-from-json-using-datacontractjsonserializer/)

Comment: Note that the type is included in the System.Web.Extensions assembly. Is it available to WinRT apps?

Comment: As per my findings so far ... yes, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

Comment: Mmmm, it does not show up in the list of supported APIs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232.aspx

Comment: .NET running on a Windows 8 host != WinRT .NET app.

Comment: Thanks but the System.Web namespace isn't available in .NET for WinRT. Regarding solution number two, it works in this scenario as all objects of hierarchy are the same, but that's not always the case in my real app (hence the use of a Dictionary<string, object> btw).

Comment: `DataContractJsonSerializer` is build to work with `DataContract` so if you go with this apporach you have to specify the `DataContract` or otherwise try defining your own custom deserialization technique using **Data Contract Surrogates**, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733064.aspx.